# How to find the intersection between a plane and a conic?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find k such that the intersection of the plane kx+y=1 and the two-sheet hyperboloid x²−y²−z²=1 is an: a) ellipse b) hyperbola.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Is that hyperboloid a "conic"? What does the word "conic" mean? I thought a conic ("conic section") was a *curve* obtained by intersecting a plane with a cone. In my book the hyperboloid was called a "quadric surface" if I remember right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two mutually orthogonal unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ that are both orthogonal to the normal of the plane.  The plane is $kx + y = 1 $, so we can take

$\mathbf{v_1} = [1, -k, 0]^T /\sqrt{1 + k^2} , \mathbf{v_2} = [0, 0, 1]^T$

Define $\mathbf{r}=[x,y,z]^T$ , then the parametric equation of the plane is

$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_0} + u_1 \mathbf{v_1} + u_2 \mathbf{v_2}$

for arbitrary scalars $u_1 , u_2 $.  The above equation can be written compactly as

$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u} \hspace{12pt}(1) $

where $ \mathbf{V} = [\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2} ] $ and $ u = [u_1, u_2]^T $

and $\mathbf{r_0} $ is any point on the plane and can be taken as $[0, 1, 0]^T$
On the other hand the equation of the given quadric is

$ \mathbf{r}^T \mathbf{Q r} = 1 \hspace{12pt} (2)$

where

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && - 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Substituting (1) into (2), we obtain,

$ (\mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u})^T Q (\mathbf{r_0} + \mathbf{V u}) = 1$

Expanding,

$ \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{V}^T Q \mathbf{V u} + 2 \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} + \mathbf{r_0}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{r_0} = 1 \hspace{12pt}(3) $

At the point, it is useful to plug in $\mathbf{Q}$, $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{r_0}$ and evaluate the terms of (3).

We have,

$\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{QV} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1 - k^2}{1 + k^2} && 0 \\ 0 && - 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{1 + k^2}} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

$ \mathbf{r_0}^T \mathbf{Q r_0} = -1 $

Hence the equation in $u_1$ and $u_2$ is

$\dfrac{(1 - k^2)}{(1 + k^2)} u_1^2 - u_2^2 - 2 \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{1 + k^2}} u_1 = 2 $

If $k = \pm 1$ , we get a parabola, so we can assume that $k \ne \pm 1 $.

Multiplying through by ${1 + k^2}$

$ (1 - k^2) u_1^2 - (1 + k^2) u_2^2 - 2 k \sqrt{1 + k^2} u_1 = 2 (1 + k^2)$

Completing the square,

$ (1 - k^2) ( u_1 - \dfrac{k \sqrt{1 + k^2}}{1 - k^2} )^2  - (1 + k^2) u_2^2 = 2 (1 + k^2) + \dfrac{k^2 (1 + k^2)}{1 - k^2} \hspace{12pt} (4) $

From (4) , it follows that if $ -1 < k < 1 $ then we get a hyperbola, and if $| k | > 1 $, we need $2 + \dfrac{k^2}{1 - k^2} \lt 0 $ to get an ellipse, i.e. $ 2(1 - k^2) + k^2 \gt 0 $ which simplifies to $k^2 \lt 2$ otherwise there is no intersection between the plane and hyperboloid.

To summarize:

- If $|k| \lt 1 $, the intersection is a hyperbola.
- If $k \in (-\sqrt{2}, -1) \cup (1, \sqrt{2})$ , then the intersection is an ellipse.
- If $k= \pm 1$, the intersection is a parabola.
- If $k = \pm \sqrt{2}$ , the intersection is a single point (tangent point).
- For all other values of $k$ there is no intersection between the plane and the hyperboloid.